# Volcar un ejecutable a disco desde los recursos

Tags: windows

Hola estoy haciendo un programa que añade una aplicacion en recursos y lo vuelca en disco. en principio se compila bien pero no vuelca en disco mi aplicacion..estuve comprobando y hago basicamente lo correcto que es añadirlo en recursos y luego escribir el fichero el problema supong que esta aqui ya que no me lo escribe:

```
WriteFile(hFile,pRes,size,&bytesWritten,NULL);
```

El código será el siguiente: Tendre el fichero con mi recurso resources.rc:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

ELEXE RCDATA "Example1.exe"
```

resource.h:

```
#ifndef RESOURCE_H_INCLUDED
#define RESOURCE_H_INCLUDED

#define ELEXE "ELEXE"

#endif // RESOURCE_H_INCLUDED
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string exe = "ELEXE";
    HRSRC res=FindResource(NULL,exe.c_str(),RT_RCDATA);

    if(res==NULL)
         cout << GetLastError();
         cout << "\n";

    int size=SizeofResource(NULL,res);

    if( !size )
        cout << 122; // Arbitrario. -> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
        cout << "\n";

    HGLOBAL hRes=LoadResource(NULL,res);

    if( !hRes )
        cout << 122; // Arbitrario. -> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
        cout << "\n";

    unsigned char *pRes=(unsigned char *)LockResource(hRes);


    HANDLE hFile=CreateFile("C:/Users/android/Desktop/pi.exe",GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,0,NULL);

    if(hFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
         cout << GetLastError();
         cout << "\n";

    DWORD bytesWritten = size;

    WriteFile(hFile,pRes,size,&bytesWritten,NULL);

    if( !WriteFile(hFile,pRes,size,&bytesWritten,NULL) )
        cout << GetLastError();
        cout << "\n";

    CloseHandle(hFile);


    ShellExecute(HWND_DESKTOP,NULL,"C:/Users/android/Desktop/pi.exe",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Errores que devuelve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tamaños diferentes ¿por qué?:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedo escribir comentarios, me faltan puntos. Lo pongo como respuesta, aunque, *tecnicamente*, no lo es.

En primer lugar, deberias comprobar si se obtuvo un tamaño correcto para el recurso:

```
int size=SizeofResource(NULL,res);

if( !size )
  return 122; // Arbitrario. -> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
```

Lo mismo, para `LoadResource( )`:

```
HGLOBAL hRes=LoadResource(NULL,res);
  if( !hRes )
    return 122; // Arbitrario. -> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
```

Luego, deberias comprobar que pasó al escribir:

```
if( !WriteFile(hFile,pRes,size,&bytesWritten,NULL) )
  return GetLastError();
```

Por lo menos, podrás descubrir que es lo que está pasando.

Hazlo, edita la pregunta, y ya *iremos viendo* lo que pasa :-)

**EDITO**

Ló único que se me ocurre es que quites

```
if( !WriteFile(hFile,pRes,size,&bytesWritten,NULL) )
  return GetLastError();
```

y lo pongas en un bucle, *porsi escribe raro*; mi experiencia con Windows es *limitadilla*. Lamento no poder ser de mas ayuda :-(

```
BOOL ret;
while( ( ret = WriteFile(hFile,pRes,size,&bytesWritten,NULL) ) && ( size != bytesWritten ) );

if( !ret )
  return GetLastError();
```

Comment: @Perl He editado la respuesta. Prueba ahora, a ver que pasa :-?

Comment: @Perl no se me ocurre nada mas :-( Tendrás que esperar a que alguien te responda.

Comment: hola disculpa por tanto tardar hice con un cout para mostrar y parece que si muestra errores osea que devuelve valores lo que pasa que con un print o cout se puede visualizar hago la modificacion al post de nuevo

Comment: creo que el error esta aqui en res no adquiere valor cuando le asigno el valor con findresource me muestra el error 1814 eso quiere decir que no esta asignando un valor por tanto es nulo?

Comment: @Perl, cambia el `resource.h` y pon `#define ELEXE "ELEXE"`.  Creo que el problema está aquí, `""` creo que no es válido como nombre de recurso.

Comment: si funciona ambas son las misma aplicacion solamente me cambia el tamaño lo cual no sé porque supongo será por algo de rcdata ok supongo que alineara los datos en bloques como especificastes.

Comment: @Perl, no uso Windows, pero casi seguro que el sistema de recursos *alinea* los datos en bloques de un tamaño fijo. Si se usan bloques de 512 bytes, y un recurso ocupa 600, se ocuparán 2 bloques, por lo que el tamaño del recurso será de 1024 bytes.

Comment: @Perl no deberías de preocuparte por eso. En ejecutables, el tamaño *util* va en la cabecera. Aunque ocupe mas bytes, no afecta al funcionamiento del ejecutable.